# Missing Events in GA4 Daily Tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

We have found that we are missing many events in the GA4 BigQuery daily rollup tables. We have streaming enabled, as well as the daily rollup tables. In our website, we have a pretty standard flow that is common for all users and instrumented with two events:

**Event Name:** "custom_click"

**Event Parameters:**

```
[
   {name: "custom_category", value: "Data Gather"}
   {name: "custom_entity_name", value: "Shop"}
   {name: "custom_entity_type", value: "Button"}
   {name: "custom_param_1", value: "Zip Code"}
   {name: "custom_param_2", value: "Employee Count"}
   {name: "custom_param_3", value: "SIC Code"}
]
```

**Event Name:** "custom_submit"

**User Properties:**

```
[
   {name: "custom_uid", value: "Guid"}
]
```

**Event Parameters:**

```
[
   {name: "custom_category", value: "Data Gather"}
   {name: "custom_entity_name", value: "Shop"}
   {name: "custom_entity_type", value: "Button"}
   {name: "custom_param_1", value: "Zip Code"}
   {name: "custom_param_2", value: "Employee Count"}
   {name: "custom_param_3", value: "Date"}
   {name: "custom_param_4", value: "SIC Code"}
]
```

In our testing and review of the aggregate report data, we're seeing both events consistently in the intraday table, but we're seeing Google "sample" or remove a portion of the custom_submit event from making it into the daily table. This is difficult because that event also sets the custom_uid user property/dimension for the user's session going forward, so if it's missing there's a good chance that it would be missing from future events in the final rollup.

From our reading, we have seen that Google may sample the data if you have Google Signal enabled, which we did orginally, but have since disabled. It seemed to help for a while, but then the problem returned after a week.

We don't believe this is an issue with the event instrumentation on the website because we have conclusively proved through testing that we see the events in the intraday table and then those same events (identified by session ID and timestamp) are gone when the daily table is updated (and after their 3 day SLA).

We have verified that the events visible in the GA4 Report interface align to the events in the daily tables, so the same problem affects the reports that we can generate through GA4.

This makes using the GA4 to BigQuery solution really difficult to rely on. Any ideas or reasons on why this could be happening would be super helpful.